# GORM: populate list into select dropdown

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am working on a Grails form item that just populates a list of FaqCategories from an FaqCategory domain class.   All I want the select dropdown to do is display the list.   So far, this sort of works, but I'm not sure how to generate the list or what to put in the Value section if anything.

```
Form item:

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <g:select name="Category" from="${FaqCategory.list()}" required="" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="faqCategory-label" value=""/>
    </div>
```

Domain class #1

```
class Faq {

    String question
    String answer
    FaqCategory faqCategory

    static constraints ={
        question nullable:false, maxSize:1000
        answer nullable:false, maxSize:1000
        faqCategory nullable:false
    }
}
```

Domain class #2

class FaqCategory {

```
String categoryType

String toString(){
    "$categoryType" 
}

static constraints = {
    categoryType nullable:true, maxSize:100, unique:true
}
```

}

Controller snippet

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
def create() {
    respond new Faq(params)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller code :

```
yourAction(int id){

  //do some 
   def faqInstance = Faq.get(id)
   render[view:"form",model:[faqInstance:faqInstance]]
}
```

### View code :

```
<g:select name="faqCategory"
          from="${FaqCategory.list()}"
          value="${faqInstance?.faqCategory?.categoryType}"
          optionKey="id" />
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to show the context in which this select is being used so it is hard to say exactly what you need, but something like this should work:

```
<g:select name="faqCategory"
          from="${FaqCategory.list()}"
          value="${you only need this if you want to preselect a value}"
          optionKey="id" />
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html for more details.

I hope that helps.

Comment: It's weird - sometimes that will work just fine.  But every once in a while I get something like "Cannot get constructor" or "faqCategory is null" types of errors.

Comment: There could be any number of things in your app which might lead to that. The example I show will create an input field in your form and the input field will be named `faqCategory`.  When the form is submitted the value of the `faqCategory` request parameter will correspond to the item that you have selected.  In your controller you can retrieve the value of that parameter directly if you like or more likely it will be used during mass property assignment with something like `new Faq(params)` or `faqInstance.properties=params`. You may have something wrong in your code that is using the value.